# Spring boot - Couchbase AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration - How to avoid overriding unnecessary methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am connecting to couchbase using my spring boot app. It's connecting fine and everything works.
Here's my configuration class for a @ReadingConverter.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = "com.mypackage.repositories")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class CouchbaseRepoConfiguration extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableEnvironment env;

    /************** String to byte[] conversion - Starts here **************/
    @Override
    public CouchbaseCustomConversions customConversions() {
        return new CouchbaseCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(StringToByteConverter.INSTANCE));
    }

    @ReadingConverter
    public static enum StringToByteConverter implements Converter<String, byte[]> {
        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public byte[] convert(String source) {
            return Base64.decodeBase64(source);
        }
    }

    /************** String to byte[] conversion - Ends here **************/

    @Override
    protected List<String> getBootstrapHosts() {
        return Arrays.asList(env.getProperty("spring.couchbase.bootstrap-hosts"));
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBucketName() {
        return env.getProperty("spring.couchbase.bucket.name");
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBucketPassword() {
        return env.getProperty("spring.couchbase.bucket.password");
    }
}
```

Of course, the above mentioned three properties are defined in the application.properties file.

They're the default spring couchbase credentials properties which work even if I don't have the above configuration class.

My question is: How can I only define the

> @ReadingConverter

and not override the three methods

> getBootstrapHosts()
>
> getBucketName()
>
> getBucketPassword()

Because, that is boilerplate code and doesn't really do anything.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, there is no other way to do that.